# Python: Way to count the number of tuples and lists

Tags: python, logic

Hey I trying to build a function where tuples and lists are treated as "AND" and "OR" logical components. Therefore I want to decompose a list in its components, maybe in a recursive function until there is only a list without any sublists or subtuples. Is there a way to count the number of lists and tuples in a list? Or is there even a better way to build a logical boolean expression from such a list? The smallest element is always a tuple in a style like this: (x,0,1).

**Example of a list:**

```
lst=[[(('a',0,49),('b',0,70)),(('c',0,49),('d',0,100))],[(('e',0,49),('f',0,70)),(('g',0,49),('h',0,100))]]
```

**Wanted output:**

elements in a lists are treated with "OR", elements in a tuple are treated as "AND".
So for this input list, something like this would be the dsired output or expression:

```
np.logical_or(np.logical_or(np.logical_and(a,b),np.logical_and(c,d)),np.logical_or(np.logical_and(e,f),np.logical_and(g,h))
```

Where a to h are masks

Comment: You want just a flat, 1D list of items at the end?

Comment: Also, why is this tagged `numpy`?

Comment: Yes but in every step of reduction I need to know the number of tuples and lists

Comment: What would be the desired output for some of the sub tuples/lists as well as the entire expression you gave?

Comment: Please define the _exact_ output you're looking for (is it a count? Of what exactly? Is it a "logical boolean expression"? And if so what does that mean exactly?).